# Click the menu that use span class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The code snippet of the page and have the link where I need to click.

```
<div class="xwq" style="position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px">
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%">
<div id="pt1:sdi1" class="af_showDetailItem" style="position:absolute;width:auto;height:auto;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px">
<div>
<a id="pt1:cb1" class="xfc p_AFTextOnly" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<span class="x106">Cadastro de cliente</span>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a id="pt1:cb2" class="xfc p_AFTextOnly" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<span class="x106">Relacionar cliente à Proposta de Venda</span>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a id="pt1:cb3" class="xfc p_AFTextOnly" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<span class="x106">Iniciar processo de Análise de Crédito</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Command in selenium was used :

```
WebElement menuCadCliente = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cadastro de cliente"));
menuCadCliente.click();
```

What has been identified is that a single class and inside it has different values ​​. This is my if I have not understood erroado.

Comment: Does not work with the command .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you are getting an exception when you invoke `menuCadCliente.click()`:

```
WebElement menuCadCliente = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a#pt1\\:cb1 span.x106"));
menuCadCliente.click();
```

Comment: Does not work with the command . Have any other suggestions .

Comment: @Renato Santana: What happens when you try it? Do you get an exception when you invoke click() on the element, or does the click() method fail silently?

Comment: does the click() method fail silently?

Comment: messagem erro: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector a#pt1:cb1 span.x106 is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: @Renato Santana: I have updated my answer to use an escape sequence for the colon. What browser are you using and which version? Do you need to use any other browsers/versions?